# Using matched pattern to rewrite a new pattern

Tags: php

Basically, I want to map from URL pattern to another URL pattern. For example:

```
news.php?id=(\d+)  ->  news/$1
```

I manage to do the following with a simple loop.

```
$url = "news.php?id=24";
$pattern = "/news.php\?id=(\d+)/";
$rewrite = "news/$1";

if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $match))
{
    for($i = 1; $i < count($match); $i++) {
        $rewrite = str_replace("\${$i}", $match[$i], $rewrite);
    }
}

var_dump($rewrite);
// output: news/24
```

I wonder whether there is a better way or a native PHP function that can do a similiar thing?

**NOTE:** Please don't suggest to use .htaccess because I attempt to make a routing system and the above is just a sample code that I test before I plug into the actual engine.

Comment: It's been a little while since I've done this stuff, but wouldn't preg_replace() be suitable?

Comment: How would you implement a router without `.htaccess`??! You probably want you `.htaccess` to be pure without heavy conditions.

Comment: And also, a router makes sense only if you have a `Front Controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be easier?

```
preg_replace("/news.php\?id=(\d+)/","news/$1","news.php?id=24")
```

Comment: You have the order of the arguments for preg_replace incorrect. It should be `preg_replace("/news.php\?id=(\d+)/","news/$1","news.php?id=24")`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Thanks! Will update the answer to the correct one (for future generations).